# Javascript - callback with objects

Tags: javascript, callback

I have a problem with callback function. I want write a function, who
   can iterate the object (i want use a callback method), but it's not
   working and i don't know what is wrong with this.

I'll be glad from any help.

```
   services = [
    {
        name: "a",
    }, 
    {
        name: "b"
    }
   ]

   function Service (data) {
    this.name = data.name
   }

   function getData (i) {
    sample = new Service(services[i])
    console.log(sample)
   }

   getData(0) /* this function work*/

   function getAll(index, count, callback) {
    service = new Service(services[index]);
    console.log(service)
    if (index < count) {
        callback(index + 1, count, getAll)
    }
   }

   getAll (0, services.length, getAll) /* this function is not working */
```

Comment: "not working" is not a very good description of a problem !

Comment: TypeError: Cannot read property 'name' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you get is due to calling services[2] that doesn't exists.
This getAll function below solves your problem

```
   function getAll(index, count, callback) {
       if (index < count) {
           service = new Service(services[index]);
           console.log(service)
           callback(index + 1, count, getAll)
       }
   }
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the

```
 getAll (0, services.length, getAll)
```

services.length return the length of an array, but arrays start at position 0

to fix this error use

```
 getAll (0, services.length-1, getAll)
```